# Confused with naming convention for Springs @ModelAttribute annotation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, modelattribute

The official documentation doens't answer my question fully and I kindly ask for your help.

Is is true that the name of the `@ModelAttribute` has to be the same as the actual object `Pet pet` (a)? Or can it also be different (b)?

```
@PostMapping("/owners/{ownerId}/pets/{petId}/edit")
(a) public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet, BindingResult r) {
(b) public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("cat") Dog rex, BindingResult r 
    if (r.hasErrors()) {
        return "petForm";
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be different, the name of `@ModelAttribute` must match the attribute that It is used in the view. If you do not indicate the name, Spring take the name of the variable by default.